# jQueryUI SelectMenu jumps to top of page when menu is opened/clicked in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the jQueryUI SelectMenu with a themeroller and it's working great in Chrome and Firefox. However, in IE8 (my lowest version needed and first IE to test), when I click the menu, the screen jumps to the top of the page, as if I had a bookmark/href to the top of the page (I don't).

When I scroll down the page in Firefox or Chrome, then click the select menu, the dropdown appears and I can make a selection. When I repeat the steps in IE8, the page jumps to the top when I click the select menu.

Does anyone know if this is a bug with the SelectMenu and/or if there's any way to prevent it from happening?

My code is pretty basic and I'm providing it in case someone notices that I've implemented something wrong in the SelectMenu. I'm generating the content with Powershell (in the 'generated_content' div), in case that's important to anyone. Here's the snippet of HTML:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
<h1>Report</h1>
<h3>Report Run Date: *Date*</h3>
<hr class='title_separator'>

<div class='selector'></div>

<div class='generated_content'></div>

</div>
```

Here's the snippet of jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selector').append("<span id='space'>Select an item</span>: ");
    $('.selector').append("<select label='Select an item:' id='select_item'> </select>");
    $('#select_item').append("<option selected disabled value=''>  </option>");
    $('#select_item').append("<option value='all'>All</option>");

    $('#select_item').selectmenu()

    var changeSelect = function(event, item) {
        $(this).trigger('change', item);
    };

    $('#select_item').selectmenu({change:changeSelect});

    $('#select_item').change(function() {
        $('#select_item option:selected').each(function() {
            $('.generated_content').hide();

            if ($(this).attr("value")=="all") {
                $('.generated_content').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
            }       
        });
    });
});

$(window).load(function() {
    $('#selector').selectmenu('refresh');
});
```

**jQuery Versions**

I'm currently using jQuery 1.11.2 with jQueryUI 1.11.3. I also tried jQuery 1.9.0 with jQueryUI 1.10.0.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: As @BramVanroy asked which version of jquery you use i will just say that  IE8 supports jquery below 2.x

Comment: Can you get this replicated in a fiddle? That would be a HUGE help in me helping you

Comment: Updated the post with version info.

Comment: Working example would be helpful and I can't see the usage of `changeSelect` function, can you explain the usage?

Comment: Did you try to look at the console for any errors in IE8?

Comment: I added the `changeSelect` function...not sure how I missed copying that in the first time. I looked at the console and it appears as though there may be something in the SelectMenu that's triggering the page to offset back to the top in IE8 that's not occurring in Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: I have a theory. Can you tell us what the layout of your page is like? When you say "jumping to the top", what do you mean specifically? Does the dropdown go out of view? I ask because I am wondering if because you are hiding the generated content section then immediately reshowing it or other sections if the actual document height is getting shorter then taller in the course of a couple of milliseconds. And maybe the other browsers are smart enough not to move the scroll bar, but IE8 is. What if you try hiding the generated content block ONLY if All is not selected...

Comment: I guess the page is actually 'jumping' any time a selection is made. It's noticeable when the selection is 'All'. However, when 'All' is selected, the screen 'jumps' to the top of the page, but it doesn't jump all the way to the top of the page. There's still some 10-15px between the top of the screen & the start of the wrapper div (the screen jumps really jumps to the top of the wrapper div, to be more succinct). If I hide the generated content only if 'All' is not selected, then I will have individual content divs that appear, when they're supposed to replace each other. Is there a toggle?

Comment: Due to time constraints for the project I'm working on, I had to remove the jQueryUI SelectMenu from my solution. I believe that @jwatts1980 was probably on the right track, but I'll be unable to investigate further at this time. I appreciate the help received from everyone. Thanks again.